# Dividing a whole column with a certain value in CSV file with python [normalizing data]

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to normalize all data from certain columns in CSV file using python.
For example:

```
Name_1,Data_1,Data_2,Data_3,Data_4     #Header row
Smith,100,200,300,400
Johnson,110,210,310,410
Williams,111,222,333,444
```

How to divide let's say the whole Data_2 and the whole Data_4 column with 100?
To get something like this:

```
Name_1,Data_1,Data_2,Data_3,Data_4     #Header row
Smith,100,0.2,300,0.4
Johnson,110,0.21,310,0.41
Williams,111,0.222,333,0.444
```

Is it possible to do it without using pandas? This is what I've written so far and got stuck now.

```
import csv

with open(input_file.csv, 'r') as infile, open(output_file.csv, 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(next(reader))
    writer.writerows(row[1]/100 for row in reader)
    writer.writerows(row[3]/100 for row in reader)   #Should here be something that writes columns and not rows?
outfile.close()
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: I'm not sure normalizing is the correct terminology here. You are scaling everything down by a factor of 100. Normalizing would be dividing each column value by the maximum in that column which would normalize everything to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'r', newline='') as infile, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)

    rows = list(reader)
    header = rows[0]
    data = rows[1:]

    def div(this_row):
        # I changed it to divide by 1000 to make the output match what you wanted
        return [this_row[0], this_row[1], float(this_row[2])/1000, this_row[3], float(this_row[4])/1000]
    new_data = [div(row) for row in data]

    new_rows = [header] + new_data
    for row in new_rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

`output.csv`:

```
Name_1,Data_1,Data_2,Data_3,Data_4
Smith,100,0.2,300,0.4
Johnson,110,0.21,310,0.41
Williams,111,0.222,333,0.444
```

Comment: Yeah it was a typo /1000.
I get the same error _IndexError: list index out of range_

Comment: Ok, that's interesting... It runs without errors on my machine... What OS are you running? Could you publish the value of `rows` after running the program?

Comment: I have Windows 10 Home. It returns empty .csv file. I tried removing header row first and then normalizing the data, same result.

Comment: I see what's the problem here.. I'm trying to run it over multiple csv files which contains different number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the core question is about doing a division on selected fields. Here's a slimmed down version that uses a couple pythonic tools (list comprehension, zip).

```
import csv
import io

input_file = io.StringIO('''Name_1,Data_1,Data_2,Data_3,Data_4
Smith,100,200,300,400
Johnson,110,210,310,410
Williams,111,222,333,444
'''
)

reader = csv.reader(input_file)
data_normalizations = [1, 1000, 1, 1000]
output = []
for i, row in enumerate(reader):
  if i == 0:  # Header row.
    output.append(row)
  else:
    output.append([row[0]] + [int(a)/b for a,b in zip(row[1:], data_normalizations)])

output
```

for me, this returns

```
[['Name_1', 'Data_1', 'Data_2', 'Data_3', 'Data_4'],
 ['Smith', 100.0, 0.2, 300.0, 0.4],
 ['Johnson', 110.0, 0.21, 310.0, 0.41],
 ['Williams', 111.0, 0.222, 333.0, 0.444]]
```

which should be straightforward for you to write to CSV.